# Diferencias Matriz Transpuestas

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda que la dejo aca porque no entiendo el porque, no se si es algo interno de los tipos de variables o que seria. pero la cuestion es esta, lo de calcular la matriz transpuesta con la clase Vector y tambien con el tipo **int:Entonces ambas funciones dan distinto. Pero en esencia es el mismo calculo:

```
int**  transpuesta(int **dir_matriz, int nfilas, int ncol){
    int **dir_Mataux;
    dir_Mataux = dir_matriz;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++){    
        
        for(int j = 0; j < ncol; j++){
            if(i != j){
            
                *(*(dir_matriz + i ) + j ) = *(*(dir_Mataux + j) + i);
            }
        
        }
        
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    
    
    return dir_matriz;
}
```

Ahora la misma funcion pero con la clase Vector

```
vector <vector<int> >transpuesta2(vector<vector<int> > &mat){

   vector<vector<int> > mat2;

   mat2 = mat;

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++){
        
        
        for(int j = 0; j < mat[0].size(); j++){
            if(i != j){
            
        mat[i][j] = mat2[j][i];
           }
        
        }
        
           
    }
        cout<<"\n";
    
    
    return mat;
    
}
```

El codigo lo que hace es, dada una matriz calcula su transpuesta. Por ejemplo si

```
mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

si calculo mat con la primera funcion me da de resultado

```
{{1,4,7},{4,5,8},{7,8,9}}
```

si calculo mat en la segunda funcion me da bien el resultado que es

```
{{1,4,7}{2,5,8}{3,6,9}}
```

Porque da distinto? si las instrucciones son las mismas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pero en esencia es el mismo calculo

Sí y no.

Dejan de ser el mismo cálculo en el momento en el que, en la primera función, `dir_Mataux`y `dir_matriz` apuntan a la misma región de memoria.

En efecto, es lo que consigues con la siguiente instrucción:

```
dir_Mataux = dir_matriz;
```

Dado que `dir_Mataux` es un puntero, lo que hace la asignación es modificar la dirección de memoria a la que apunta dicho puntero.

Si tu idea es clonar `dir_matriz` tendrás que hacerlo a mano:

```
int ** dir_Mataux = new int*[nfilas];
for( int i=0; i<nfilas; i++ )
{
    dir_Mataux[i] = new int[ncol];
    for( int j=0; j<ncol; j++ )
    {
        dir_Mataux[i][j] = dir_matriz[i][j];
    }
}

// calculo de la traspuesta
// ...

// Liberamos la memoria reservada
for( int i=0; i<nfilas; i++ )
{
  delete[] dir_Mataux[i];
}
delete[] dir_Mataux;
```